# Doctrine: entity repository local cache

Tags: doctrine-orm

I find myself doing something like this very often in my repositories:

```
protected $currencies;


public function findAll()
{
    if (!isset($this->currencies))
    {
        $this->currencies = parent::findAll();
    }

    return $this->currencies;
}
```

So all services that need the collection of entity objects 
can just call `findAll` on the repository
without starting database query/hydration process more than once.

Is it right or am I misusing Repository pattern?
What is Your way of keeping collections locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do something like this, you are probably abusing your controllers/services. Is there some reason you need cached results within memory when this is live only during request? Ie once the page loads, all of this is gone.

This only makes sense if you use same findAll results multiple times within page and that is what you need to fix.

Comment: That is only possible if services do not depend on repositories, otherwise you cannot be sure findAll is called only once during one request.

Comment: Still the same question: why would you need to call $repo->findAll() two or more times per page? It doesn't matter if that is from controller or service.

Comment: Suppose I have 2 independent services that use the same entity collection (like currencies). I may inject the collection in their constructors instead of the repo, but that forces me to always preload (findAll) objects from database before instantiating the services (no lazy load). What if the service is created but not used? I have useless db query (findAll).